# Как отключить кнопку для определенных людей discord

Tags: discord, disnake

Представим, что я сделал кнопку меню в discord, которая недоступна заранее определенным пользователям, а всем остальным доступна (т.е. все могут нажать на кнопку, заранее определенные люди не могут). Язык python, библиотека disnake или discord.py (как удобнее будет тому, кто ответит)
код кнопки:

```
class Menu_Button(disnake.ui.View): 

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Меню", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green)
    async def menu_button(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title="Выбирай, что тебя интересует!",
            description="Если не получается что-нибудь выбрать, то нажми на кнопку \"Меню\" (она выше) ещё раз",
            color=0x00a2ff
        
        )
        await inter.response.send_message(
            embed=embed,
            view=DropDownView_36(),
            ephemeral=True
            )
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так сообщение выглядит у всех
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Так выглядит сообщение у заранее определенного пользователя (только без надписи "изменено")